# How to convert column of MapType(StringType, StringType) into StringType?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

So I have this streaming dataframe and I'm trying to cast this 'customer_ids' column to a simple string.

```py
schema = StructType()\
    .add("customer_ids", MapType(StringType(), StringType()))\
    .add("date", TimestampType())

original_sdf = spark.readStream.option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 800)\
    .load(path=source, ftormat="parquet", schema=schema)\
    .select('customer_ids', 'date')
```

The intend to this conversion is to group by this column and agregate by max(date) like this

```py
original_sdf.groupBy('customer_ids')\
  .agg(max('date')) \
  .writeStream \
  .trigger(once=True) \
  .format("memory") \
  .queryName('query') \
  .outputMode("complete") \
  .start()
```

but I got this exception

```py
AnalysisException: u'expression `customer_ids` cannot be used as a grouping expression because its data type map<string,string> is not an orderable data type.
```

How can I cast this kind of streaming DataFrame column or any other way to groupBy this column?

Comment: Please provide some input/output data.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** Use `getItem` method to access the values per key in a `MapType` column.

---

The real question is what key(s) you want to `groupBy` since a `MapType` column can have a variety of keys. Every key can be a column with values from the map column.

You can access keys using [Column.getItem](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@getItem(key:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) method (or a similar python voodoo):

> **getItem(key: Any): Colum** An expression that gets an item at position ordinal out of an array, or gets a value by key key in a MapType.

(I use Scala and am leaving converting it to pyspark as a home exercise)

```
val ds = Seq(Map("hello" -> "world")).toDF("m")
scala> ds.show(false)
+-------------------+
|m                  |
+-------------------+
|Map(hello -> world)|
+-------------------+

scala> ds.select($"m".getItem("hello") as "hello").show
+-----+
|hello|
+-----+
|world|
+-----+
```